# Error while converting Datatype due to DBNulls

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, dbnull

I am trying to load data using my c# application by calling a stored procedure from one database and would then need to insert that data into another database. I am planning to using SQL bulk insert for it. I did propose SSIS but unfortunately they don't have the software and infrastructure for it. I need to convert the datatype for some of my columns as it blows up when I do bulk insert into destination table. I am using a function to the conversion but unfortunately getting an error when trying to convert `DBNull` value. When I try to check for `DBNull` value prior to conversion it doesn't seem to enter the If condition block. Could somebody tell me where am I going wrong?

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_SourceConnectionString))
{
    // con.Open();

    // Create a table with some rows. 
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    var cmd = new SqlCommand("[EMR].[spOrderDailySummary]", con);
    var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrderDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = _businessDate;

    try
    {
        // LogManager.Log(LogSeverity.Info, $"Initiating report {rgc.ReportType}.");
        da.Fill(table);

        table.ConvertColumnType("Original_Qty", typeof(int));
        table.ConvertColumnType("Remaining_Qty", typeof(int));
        table.ConvertColumnType("Price", typeof(decimal));
        table.ConvertColumnType("OrderDate", typeof(DateTime));
        table.ConvertColumnType("Valid_to_Value", typeof(DateTime));
        table.ConvertColumnType("ClientID", typeof(int));
        table.ConvertColumnType("Trigger_Price", typeof(decimal));
        table.ConvertColumnType("Investment_Decision_Within_Firm", typeof(int));
        table.ConvertColumnType("Order_Priority_Timestamp", typeof(DateTime));
        table.ConvertColumnType("Transaction_Time", typeof(DateTime));
        table.ConvertColumnType("NewOrdDateTime", typeof(DateTime));

        StartDataMigration(table);
    }
}
```

Function that does the conversion

```
  public static void ConvertColumnType<T>(this DataTable dt, string columnName, Type newType) where T : Type, IConvertible
{
    using (DataColumn dc = new DataColumn(columnName + "_new", newType))
    {
        // Add the new column which has the new type, and move it to the ordinal of the old column
        int ordinal = dt.Columns[columnName].Ordinal;
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);
        dc.SetOrdinal(ordinal);

        // Get and convert the values of the old column, and insert them into the new
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            if (dr[dc.ColumnName] != DBNull.Value)
            {
                dr[dc.ColumnName] = Convert.ChangeType(dr[columnName], newType);
            }

        // Remove the old column
        dt.Columns.Remove(columnName);

        // Give the new column the old column's name
        dc.ColumnName = columnName;
    }
}
```

Comment: `dt.Columns.Add(dc);` adds a reference to `dc` but the object is created into a `using` statement and would be disposed. I haven't tested this code but I'd suggest debugging and check whether `dt.Columns` contains the newly added column after leaving `using` code block `{ ... }`.

Comment: `if (dr[dc.ColumnName]` should be `if (dr[columnName]`?

Comment: If you've read a lot of my posts here, you know I love `using` blocks. But the DataColumn in this question is a situation where'd I skip it. The reason is we don't really want to dispose the column until the DataTable is also disposed, and we can have reasonable confidence (even though the DataTable.Dispose() method isn't actually documented) the DataTable will properly dispose any of its member column objects when that happens.

Comment: Also, IIRC, you can't trust comparing to DBNull.Value using `==` or `!=` directly. You have to use `DBNull.Value.Equals()` or `IsDBNull()`

Comment: The DataRow.IsNull method instead?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.isnull?view=net-5.0

Comment: I am getting error saying object should implement IConvertible . So I have updated my post to show how I have done it. Not sure how to call the method

Comment: how do I call this table.ConvertColumnType<what do I pass here ?>("Original_Qty", typeof(int));

Comment: You'll have to abandon `Convert.ChangeType`. Do the conversion manually: `if (dr[columnName].GetType() == typeof(SomeType))) // convert from SomeType to desired type` and so on.

Comment: Not sure why I need to do dr[columnName].GetType() this as I know what type I need to convert it to and I beleive the data table in the initial load will have everthing to type string. So in my logic I am trying to convert specific columns and those columns I need to convert it to type I am passing to the function

Comment: Or I am wondering is better I define column type at the very beginning before loading data into it like this  table.Columns.Add("Original_Qty", typeof(int)); Then there is no need to convert the type later

Answer (score 0):

This line is problematic:

```
if (dr[dc.ColumnName] != DBNull.Value)
```

The reason is two-fold. First, weird things can happen with comparing to `DBNull.Value` using the `!=` and `==` operators. This would be better:

```
if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(dr[dc.ColumnName]))
```

Additionally, the code above is looking at the new column name, which doesn't yet have a value set. We still need to reference the old column at this point, and so we want this:

```
if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(dr[columnName]))
```

Comment: this check that you have suggested is definetly better. I am getting error saying object should implement IConvertible . So I have update my post to show how I have done it. Not sure how to call the method

Comment: how do I call this table.ConvertColumnType<what do I pass here ?>("Original_Qty", typeof(int));

Comment: @Tom Generics MUST resolve at compile time. There is no way to use a run-time type instance there. You may need to a switch statement or similar to call a separate method for each of the types supported by DataTable, or a switch inside the one method. But you can specify the type name, ie `table.ConvertColumnType<int>("Original_Qty", typeof(int));` The problem is it's the _old type_ that needs to be convertible.

Comment: If I am calling by table.ConvertColumnType<int>("Original_Qty", typeof(int)) , I get error int cannot be used as parameter There is no boxing conversion from "int" to 'T'

Comment: I am not too sure if what you meant by need to have switch statement in the one method. What would I need to check in the switch statement

Comment: Or I am wondering is better I define column type at the very beginning before loading data into it like this  table.Columns.Add("Original_Qty", typeof(int)); Then there is no need to convert the type later

Comment: Yes, that would be MUCH better. What you're trying to do now is stupid slow, anyway, effectively doubling the time to complete most queries. Additionally, ADO.Net should **already** be setting types on the columns.